# Rails Login not refreshed even after restarting the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Why is that even restarting the Webbrick Server, the application remembers the previous login? How to make the User login again each time the user restarts?  I am using Devise gem for login/signup.

Comment: Since it is using the value stored in a cookie that the browser is sending you.  Closing the user's browser should get rid of the cookie. or you can create a logout button that deletes the user's session.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually, I had not used before_filter :authenticate_user! in controller.